# SalesForce permanent access token key generation

Tags: authentication

I'm trying to pull SF records into Sql server using SSIS ETL tools. For that I'm using the SF authentication with valid credentials but SF credentials expires every 12 hrs and I've to again generate the new access token key and update in my application. This is a very tangy process, so can anyone help me out how to generate the permanent access token key with the help of refresh token key.

Comment: I'll be interested in any answer you get.   I currently complete something similar but I "login" each time I download from SF.  I presumed the token expires is simply a security feature.

Comment: Hi Panda, Indeed the token key expires every 8/12 hrs I guess and every time I've to update the new access token key before the Jobs execution. If you don't mind can you please share me ur contact details so that I can discuss you in brief.